# Select a row in treeview using keyboard Ctrl+Enter

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, ttk

I'm working on some problem concerning the selection one row after other. I modify above code and recive the total selection of treeview when I press Ctrl+Enter. What should I do to add one row by pressing Ctrl+Enter and when press one more time Ctrl+Enter I add a second row?

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class App(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.CreateUI()
        self.grid(sticky = (tk.N,tk.S,tk.W,tk.E))
        parent.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        parent.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

    def CreateUI(self):
        tv = ttk.Treeview(self,yscrollcommand=sc.set,height=30)
        tv['columns'] = ('Name',)
        tv.heading("#0", text='Items')
        tv.column("#0", anchor="w",width=75)
        tv.heading('Name', text='Name')
        tv.column('Name', anchor='w', width=150)
        tv.grid(sticky = (tk.N,tk.S,tk.W,tk.E))
        self.treeview = tv
        self.treeview.bind('<Return>',self.OnClick)

    def OnClick(self,event):
        rows = self.treeview.get_children()
        for row in rows:
            self.treeview.selection_add(row)
       
        

items=[]
for i in range(100):
    items.append([i,'Item %d' % i])

root=tk.Tk()
sv=tk.StringVar()
filt=tk.Entry(root,textvariable=sv)
filt.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='nw')
sc=tk.Scrollbar(root)
sc.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky='ns')
item_list=App(root)
item_list.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky='ns')
sc.config(command=item_list.treeview.yview)
for i in range(len(items)):
    item_list.treeview.insert('', 'end', iid=str(i), text=items[i][0], values=(items[i][1],))
item_list.treeview.selection_set('0')

def update_filter(*args):
    global items,item_list,sv
    filtr=sv.get().lower()
    item_list.treeview.delete(*(item_list.treeview).get_children())
    for i in range(len(items)):
        if filtr in str(items[i][0]).lower() or filtr in str(items[i][1]).lower():
            item_list.treeview.insert('', 'end', iid=str(i), text=items[i][0], values=(items[i][1],))
    item_list.treeview.update()
    item_list.update()

sv.trace('w', update_filter)
filt.focus()
root.mainloop()
```

output:

[image]

Comment: I don't see any bindings for control-enter in your code. Are you asking how to bind to control-enter?

Comment: self.treeview.bind('<Control-Enter>',self.OnClick) - is not working.

Comment: I'm asking how to highlight one row after other by using a Control +Enter.

Comment: Yes, but your code doesn't show any attempt at trying to do that.

Comment: It must be easy, but i can't find any solution :(

Comment: Could you help me to  improve this code.

Comment: You seemed to show in a comment that you know how to do a binding, so why don't you try doing that and then explain what happened.

Comment: I'm beginner. Could you help me to improve this code. ?

Comment: I paste the binding self.treeview.bind('<Control-Enter>',self.OnClick) in code but it's not working. Sorry for my English.

Comment: "not working" is a useless phrase. _how_ is it not working? _show_ us what you've tried.

Comment: I have tried to use a treeview.identify('item', event.x, event.y) but I think  I go wrong

Comment: Could you give me some guides ?